# Regular Expression for Int32

Tags: sql-server, regex

Im trying to write a regex for Int32 numbers. I thought about writing a regex that matches any number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, but I don't know how to write an expression that ranges from negative to positive values ..

Any ideas ?

Comment: The result of that expression will probably look really ugly! It would probably, as some answers suggest, be much easier to parse it with the language-built-in parser

Answer (score 4):

To get negative and positive values **in the range you specified** you can do this:

EDIT: numbers can start from 0 (corrected), numbers range from -2147483648 to 2147483647 not -2147483647 to 2147483648 (corrected)

```
^(
-?\d{1,9}|
-?1\d{9}|
-?20\d{8}|
-?21[0-3]\d{7}|
-?214[0-6]\d{6}|
-?2147[0-3]\d{5}|
-?21474[0-7]\d{4}|
-?214748[012]\d{4}|
-?2147483[0-5]\d{3}|
-?21474836[0-3]\d{2}|
214748364[0-7]|
-214748364[0-8]
)$
```

commenting line by line:

```
^(                  //start of line, or it will match part of the number and not the whole one
-?\d{1,9}|          //get any number with 9 digits
-?1\d{9}|           //get any number with 10 digits starting with 1
-?20\d{8}|          //get any number with 10 digits starting with 20
-?21[0-3]\d{7}|     //get any number with 10 digits starting with 21
                    //         (and the third digit in the range 0-3)
-?214[0-6]\d{6}|    //I think from now on it is understood
-?2147[0-3]\d{5}|
-?21474[0-7]\d{4}|
-?214748[012]\d{4}|
-?2147483[0-5]\d{3}|
-?21474836[0-3]\d{2}|
214748364[0-7]|     //max corner case
-214748364[0-8]     //min corner case
)$
```

Comment: Gabber, in what way will your expression (`-?\d{1,10}`) match in the original question?

Comment: Except this will allow values in the range 2,147,4883,648 - 9,999,999,999 (and the corresponding negative range) which are well outside of a 32bit int.

Comment: What about f ex `-100`?
`100`? `1`?

Comment: This was what I was looking for and couldn't find, thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `Int32.Parse(value)` instead,  you could catch `OverflowException` if `value` represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue.

Comment: I cant because the validation will not be in the code but rather in a procedure.. Let me explain more:I have a table of parameters with key-value, and each parameter is of a different type: int, decimal, ip .. etc, and the value is a string, so for each type there is a regex that checks if the value matches the associated type.

Comment: PS: I removed the C# tag form the question cz I felt it might be confusing since I dont need C# here at all

Answer (score 0):

You can do same thing using `asp:CompareValidator`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" /> 
<asp:CompareValidator ID="validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumber" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Please enter only numeric values" /
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really an ugly regex:

### With thousands separator (comma): 1,234,567

**[In action](http://regexr.com?3202g)**:

```
^
  (
   -?
    (
     1(,\d\d\d){0,3}
    |2(,\d\d\d){0,2}
    |2,(0\d\d,\d\d\d,\d\d\d
       |1[0-3]\d,\d\d\d,\d\d\d
       |14[0-6],\d\d\d,\d\d\d
       |147,[0-3]\d\d,\d\d\d
       |147,4[0-7]\d,\d\d\d
       |147,48[0-2],\d\d\d
       |147,483,[0-5]\d\d
       |147,483,6[0-3]\d
       |147,483,64[0-7])
    |[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d\d\d){0,2}
    )
  |0
  |-2,147,483,648
)$
```

### Without thousands separator: 1234567

**[In action](http://regexr.com?320jf)**:

```
^
  (
   -?
    (
     1\d{0,9}
    |2(0\d{8}
      |1[0-3]\d{7}
      |14[0-6]\d{6}
      |147[0-3]\d{5}
      |1474[0-7]\d{4}
      |14748[0-2]\d{3}
      |147483[0-5]\d{2}
      |1474836[0-3]\d
      |14748364[0-7])
    |[1-9]\d{0,8}
    )
  |0
  |-2147483648
)$
```

Comment: Can't understand why this `|2\d{0,6}` is needed

Comment: @Gabber It was redundant and removed. Thanks for pointing out.